# Google Maps, Drones, and Hezek Riah

Tags: geography, see-sight-vision-blind, hezek-riah

There are Halachos which restrict a one's ability to see into the yard of their neighbor*. Does the use of Google maps constitute Hezek Riah, since one can use it to see into the backyards of others? Would Google be found Halachically liable to pay for damages if tried in a Beis Din? What are some practical Halachos of flying drones?

Sources:

Admur Nizkei Mamon 11;
Rema 154/3;
Mechaber 357/1 “Hezek Reiyah”;
Tur 157;
Rosh Bava Basra 1;
Bava Basra 2b

Comment: One does not have to zoom in to his neighbors’ with detail. And there is the no satellite view. So is your question about using the phone map on satellite view and zooming in to see enough detail or are you asking if this ability makes the phone map assur altogether? Same about drones- one can use the drone without any photography or just over public areas.

Comment: To clarify my question, is one allowed to zoom in on their neighbor's property using this technology?